# How to find number of days from given days in js?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to find number of days if i enter startDate and endDate.from the start_date to end_date i only want to retrieve weekdays i.e monday to friday along with the offcial_leave variable
for_example:

```
let numberOfdays;
let startDate = '2022-04-04'; //yy-mm-dd format
let endDate  =  '2022-04-08';

// Below variable come from db and vary according the start and endate
// eg:- 2022-12-25 will be holiday if we select start and end in december
let holidays = ['2022-04-05', '2022-04-07' ]


numberOfdays => 3

// I want to return number of days to 3
```

How can i achieve this in  in JavaScript

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

First convert the `startDate` and `endDate` to javascript `Date`. Then, declare a variable `i` to store while looping through the date. Also, declare `holidayIndex` which stores the current index at which holiday date needs to be checked with the current date.

Inside the loop, convert the date to `YYYY-MM-DD` format (original format) to check if the current date (`isoDate`) lies between a holiday, i.e., it is not a holiday date. If the holidayIndex is at last index of array, then just check if the current date (`isoDate`) is not in the holidays array. If not found, then increment `numberOfDays` variable.

Otherwise, a holiday date is found, hence no need to increment `numberOfDays`. Just increment `holidayIndex` to be ready to match the upcoming dates for next holiday date.

Here is the solution:

```
let numberOfdays = 0;
const startDate = '2022-04-04'; //yy-mm-dd format
const endDate = '2022-04-08';

// Below variable come from db and vary according the start and endate
// eg:- 2022-12-25 will be holiday if we select start and end in december
const holidays = ['2022-04-05', '2022-04-07'];
let holidayIndex = 0;

const start = new Date(startDate);
const end = new Date(endDate);
let i = start;

while (i <= end) {
  const isoDate = i.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  if (
    (holidayIndex < holidays.length - 1 && isoDate < holidays[holidayIndex] && isoDate > holidays[holidayIndex + 1]) ||
    formattedDate !== holidays[holidayIndex]
  ) {
    numberOfdays += 1;
  } else {
    holidayIndex += 1;
  }
  i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1);
}
```